# Google Calendar ID Authorizations / Configurations

Tags: google-apps-script, settings

I have a work group that has several appointments every week. I wanted to consolidate their schedule in a google sheet via google form and than automate saving the scheduled appointments in to every respective owner of each event.

I wrote the automated code, created and synchronized the Form and Sheet scheduled, but I've encountered a block on the way: I don't have authorization to schedule events on their calendars via app (or, more specifically, via calendar ID).

Is there any configuration authorization that can allow me to do so?

Or, as an optional solution, can is there any method in Google Calendar that I can include my partners as guests in events scheduled on my own Calendar?

Right now I'm using this method:

```
CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID).createEventFromDescription(description);
```

Comment: In that case, you need to create a shared calendar that you'll give access to everyone to read it OR you can just ask each person in your group to share their calendar with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First option**

Create events on your Calendar with guests. This would create an event in your Calendar, adding the emails you want as guests.

```
function createEvent() {

  var event = {
  'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  },
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  'attendees': [
    {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
    {'email': 'example@mail.com'}, 
  ],
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault': "False",
    'overrides': [
      {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
      {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
    ],
  }
}


Calendar.Events.insert(event, "your calendar id");

}
```

I got this example from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert).

**Second option**

Get write access to the user's Calendar when submitting the form. This can be done using [Calendar ACL](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl) rules with an [onSubmit() trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1) and attaching the code to the Form:

> Warning: This would give **read** and **write** access to **all** the events of the user's calendar

```
function onSubmit(){

  var rule = {
    "role": "writer",
    "scope": {
      "type": "user",
      "value": "your_email"
    }
  }

  Calendar.Acl.insert(rule, "primary"); //"primary" is the id of each user's main calendar

}
```

The users will have to accept the permissions, otherwise you will not get access to their Calendar. Then you would have to create the events like in the First option.

More information about the ACL rules [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert), in case they are from your domain or group

Comment: Thank you for the solve. I'll try it as soon as possible, and maybe I'll try a different road first (by adding guest with another method within the loop instead of defining the guests as variables), but that was a great addition to the solution